# Extract variable name into a column and Create Long format data

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am analyzing a dataset obtained from a survey of fish consumption. The data look like this:

```
Harbor <- c("Harbor1","Harbor1","Harbor2","Harbor2")
dfish01_correctname_s1 <- c("Anchovy", "Croaker","Anchovy","Mackerel")
dfish01_qty_s1 <- c(3,NA,24,2)
dfish02_correctname_s1 <- c("Croaker", "Herring","Shrimp","False trevally")
dfish02_qty_s1 <- c(22, 12, 3, NA)
dfish03_correctname_s1 <- c("Anchovy", "Croaker","Anchovy","Mackerel")
dfish03_qty_s1 <- c(10, 9, 5, 7)

fishData <- data.frame(Harbor, dfish01_correctname_s1, 
dfish01_qty_s1, dfish02_correctname_s1, dfish02_qty_s1, 
dfish03_correctname_s1, dfish03_qty_s1)
```

[image]

In the above data, the variables are named as follows:

1. `Harbor` contains the names of the places where surveys were conducted
2. `dfish01`, `dfish02`, and `dfish03` denote the fish options chosen by the survey respondents. `correctname` is the name of the fish species.
3. `qty` is the quantity of fish reported by the respondents.
4. `s1` indicates that this data is from the first round of the survey (There are two more rounds).

I want to put this data into the long format, and I want to extract the fish option number into a separate column named `FishOptionNum`. Any help is appreciated. Expected output is shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tidyr::pivot_longer()`, using `names_pattern` and `names_transform` to extract fish option number from column names:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

fishData %>%
  pivot_longer(
    dfish01_correctname_s1:dfish03_qty_s1,
    names_to = c("FishOptionNum", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "dfish(\\d+)_(.+)_",
    names_transform = list(FishOptionNum = as.numeric)
  ) %>%
  select(Harbor, fishname = correctname, quantity = qty, FishOptionNum)
  

# A tibble: 12 × 4
   Harbor  fishname       quantity FishOptionNum
   <chr>   <chr>             <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 Harbor1 Anchovy               3             1
 2 Harbor1 Croaker              22             2
 3 Harbor1 Anchovy              10             3
 4 Harbor1 Croaker              NA             1
 5 Harbor1 Herring              12             2
 6 Harbor1 Croaker               9             3
 7 Harbor2 Anchovy              24             1
 8 Harbor2 Shrimp                3             2
 9 Harbor2 Anchovy               5             3
10 Harbor2 Macekrel              2             1
11 Harbor2 False trevally       NA             2
12 Harbor2 Mackerel              7             3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`:

```
setDT(fishData)
melt(
  fishData, 
  measure.vars = patterns(fishname = 'dfish[0-9]{2}_correctname', quantity = '^dfish[0-9]{2}_q'), 
  variable.name = "FishOptionNum"
)[order(Harbor)]


#      Harbor FishOptionNum       fishname quantity
#      <char>        <fctr>         <char>    <num>
#  1: Harbor1             1        Anchovy        3
#  2: Harbor1             1        Croaker       NA
#  3: Harbor1             2        Croaker       22
#  4: Harbor1             2        Herring       12
#  5: Harbor1             3        Anchovy       10
#  6: Harbor1             3        Croaker        9
#  7: Harbor2             1        Anchovy       24
#  8: Harbor2             1       Macekrel        2
#  9: Harbor2             2         Shrimp        3
# 10: Harbor2             2 False trevally       NA
# 11: Harbor2             3        Anchovy        5
# 12: Harbor2             3       Mackerel        7
```